# Why does metastability occur if data changes during setup and hold time?

Tags: timing, timing-analysis

I understand that data needs to be valid during the setup and hold windows to prevent an unknown output or metastable condition. But what I don't understand is, *why* does this happen? *Why* is it that when data toggles during the setup and hold window, output is unknown?

I tried searching for this on the internet but all I could find were posts talking about setup and hold violations, how to fix them, and they all said that data toggling during the setup and hold window causes metastability. None of them explained the "why" part.

Comment: Because if you take any flip-flop implementation and closely analyse the circuit, you will find that setup and hold requirements are direct implications of internal gate delays, and difference in net delays on clock and input lines. This may be helpful: https://www.edn.com/understanding-the-basics-of-setup-and-hold-time/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the input is continuous, and the output is discrete. In synchronous systems, this is further compounded by the fact that the decision has to be made in a finite time.

The classic analog is balancing a pencil on its point. It's likely to fall one way or the other, but the better you balance it, the longer it may stay upright for.

In an electronic circuit, the receiving latch is basically a fed-back amplifier with gain >> 1. If the input is above threshold, then it will quickly drive it all the way high. If it is below threshold, it will quickly drive low. Being at the threshold is like the pencil being on its point.

In asynchronous circuits, an arbiter circuit waits until the pencil has landed. It can wait as long as necessary.

In synchronous circuits, the decision must be made by in some finite time. It's the speed of this driving high or low process that determines how resistant a latch is to the bad effects of metastability.

We can think of the speed of the fed-back amplifier in terms of time constants. There will typically be some capacitance associated with various nodes of the amplifier, and when we are around the threshold point, the gain will tend to be linear. These two features give the amplifier circuit a well defined time constant. During each time constant, the distance from the threshold will increase by 10 (or by e, or 2, or however we define the time constant) to give us exponential growth away from the threshold with time.

Let's say we have 5 V logic with a precisely 2.5 V threshold, and a latch with a time constant of 2 ns.

Let's say we input 2.6 V. After 2 ns, the 100 mV above threshold will have increased to 1 V, for 3.6 V out. In another 2 ns, it will have hit the rail.

This speed of logic may well have a propagation time specified as 5 ns, as it can hit the rail within a couple of ns if the input is sufficiently far into the 'high' voltage range.

Now we input 2.51 V, just 10 mV above the threshold. It takes 2 ns for the difference to grow to 100 mV, 2 ns to reach a volt, and another one or two to hit the rail.

Now we input 2.501 V, 1 mV above the threshold. It's obvious where this is going, the latch will take another 2 ns to hit the rail.

Now we see the propagation delay lengthening well beyond the specified time.

Put in in 2.500001 V, it takes another 6 ns. What about 2.500000001 V? It takes yet another 6 nS to resolve. The resolution time is proportional to log of the inverse of the difference from the threshold (or the negative log if you prefer).

Let's swing the voltage between 2.499999 and 2.500001 V. At some point, the negative log of the difference between that and 2.5 V is infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Logic signals are just analog signals that are interpreted with a threshold. Digital circuits are also implemented with analog components.

The logic level is stable when voltages are well within the range of being below or above the threshold of changing between logic levels.

Whenever a signal is changing, the change is not instant, it takes finite time to travel through the ambiguous area of being stably high or low.

Within that area of being not stable the signal can be interpreted as high or low due to noise and it can cause the following gates to determine the same voltage differently or cause the next gates to turn only halfway on or only momentarily.

It also takes finite time for a signal to propagate through a logic gate so when an input changes it must be waited that the change has propagated through each and every gate so that in no part of the circuit there are old levels or indeterminate levels because they are still changing.

Therefore, for the digital circuit to work properly, the analog levels of the digital signals must be well defined and stable before the clock transition, and also after, because it also takes time for the clock signal to propagate through the gates just like it takes for the data signal.

Comment: "signal can be interpreted as high or low due to noise", can you please explain what noise here means? Do you mean a signal disturbance?

Comment: Yes. Any disturbance to the signal, or to logic chip supply pin will create problems. Especially for a signal that changes slower than required for stable operation, as the noise/disturbance added to the signal will get amplified by the input gate that receives a noisy signal and thus the output of the gate might toggle several times even if there is only one transition on the input.